# quantifying over expr_vector index

Tags: z3

In the expr_vector example from example.cpp, can we quantify over the expr_vector index. For example, if we have the following code fragment :

```
expr_vector steps(c); 
expr b = c.bool_val(true); 
for(unsigned i = 0; i<N ; i++ ) 
{  expr step = c.int_const(...)

  if( i == 0 ) b = b && step == 0 ; 
  else b = b && step == steps[i-1] + 1 ; 
  steps.push_back(step); 
}
```

can we express something like

```
expr choice = c.int_const("choice); 
b = b && 0 <= choice && choice < N; 
b = b && steps[choice] > 5 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, expr_vectors are just like normal vectors with fixed size and explicit indexing. That said, it may be possible to express your problem by the use of arrays (see e.g., the [Arrays section in the tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h26)); this may come at the cost of performance however, because depending on the different combinations of theories a different decision procedure may have to be selected.